# React generates divs without class atribute

Tags: reactjs

Server-side rendering React generates divs without class  attribute...

```
<div data-reactroot="" data-reactid="1" data-react-checksum="-2115370602"> 
<div data-reactid="2"> <div data-reactid="3">...etc
```

How to put class attribute into divs?

It's bad when you loading page, some period of time (less than 0.5-1 second), before binding classes, all divs without styles.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by css-modules-require-hook https://github.com/css-modules/css-modules-require-hook